# IBM Mobilefirst and IBM Bluemix

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I have created an IBM MobileFirst Project in eclipse and I want to deploy it in IBM Bluemix, is there any way to do that? I am using Windows 7, Eclipse Luna and jdk 1.7

Comment: Absolutely. Are you asking how to do this inside of Eclipse or a general question of how to deploy an application to Bluemix?

Comment: I'll prefer if we can do it from eclipse only, but general way is also welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, at the time of writing this answer it is currently not supported by IBM to run your Worklight/MobileFirst project on Bluemix.

You could call Bluemix services, but not put the server on Bluemix in an official capacity.

Comment: So can anyone tell me how to create a proper hybrid application that will work on both mobile and desktop in IBM Bluemix

Comment: @SaptakNiyogi that's a different question; can you ask another question please?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, no. In general, the mobile services on the IBM Bluemix platform, i.e. these:

[image]

and the IBM MobileFirst Platform (on-premise, aka Worklight) product are not directly compatible - they have different APIs. When you develop a MobileFirst Platform project, the client code is deployed to a mobile device anyway (which is also true of a mobile project built with Bluemix as a back-end), so that wouldn't be relevant in this case. What does go on the MobileFirst Platform server are the adapters - and no, they can't be deployed on Bluemix. However, Bluemix does provide other services in the "Integration" category which are similar.